# BackboneJs application not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

[Click here for the js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kL4vz9tr/)

This template should render new messages in a collection, im trying to follow [this tuorial](http://codebyexample.info/2012/03/06/backbone-baby-steps/)
with my own version that renders messages instead

```
    <div id="messages" style="width: 600px"> 
    </div>

   <script type="text/template" id="messageTemplate">
       <a href="#" class="list autoWidth <% if(has_been_read) { %> selected <% } %>">
           <div class="list-content">
               <img src="//www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=20774792" class="icon">
               <div class="data">
                   <span class="item-title-secondary fg-gray"><b><%= sender %></b></span>
               </div>
                    <span class="tertiary-text">
                        <%= message %>
                    </span>
           </div>
       </a>
   </script>
```

This is the Javascript

```
 var messagesjson = [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    message: "This is the message",
                    sender: "gabriel",
                    receiver: "gabriel",
                    has_been_read: false,
                    has_been_reported: false,
                    created_at: "2014-10-23T19:55:20+0200",
                    is_friend: false
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    message: "I'm loving this ",
                    sender: "gabriel",
                    receiver: "gabriel",
                    has_been_read: true,
                    has_been_reported: false,
                    created_at: "2014-10-23T20:02:34+0200",
                    is_friend: false
                }];

            var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults:
                {
                    id: 3,
                    message: "This is the message",
                    sender: "gabriel",
                    receiver: "gabriel",
                    has_been_read: false,
                    has_been_reported: false,
                    created_at: "2014-10-23T19:55:20+0200",
                    is_friend: false
                }
            });

            var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: "div",
                className: "listview",
                template: $('#messageTemplate').html(),
                render: function()
                {
                    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
                    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
                    return this;
                }
            });

            var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: MessageModel
            });

            var MessageCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $('#messages'),
                initialize: function()
                {
                    this.collection = new MessageCollection(messagesjson);
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function()
                {
                    var that = this;
                    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
                        that.renderMessage(item);
                    },this);
                },
                renderMessage: function(item)
                {
                    var messageview = MessageView({
                        model: item
                    });

                    this.$el.append(messageview.render().el);
                }
            });

            var messagecollectionview = new MessageCollectionView();
```

instead of rendering the messages inside the "messages" template, it doesn't render anything.

> for some reason it says a function is undefined but fails to point it
>   out outside the backbone js code , this is the order I added the
>   scripts

```
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
var messageview = MessageView({
    model: item
});
```

should really be

```
var messageview = new MessageView({
    model: item
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dethariel/f5yz202p/3/).

Comment: aren't both the same ?!

Comment: @coding_idiot I think you noticed the `new` keyword in the second example. And no, they're not the same due to that.